# Frechet Space vs Banach Space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

What is Frechet Space? Is a Banach a Frechet space? If not, why? If yes, how do we prove it?
According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_space),

> Frechet spaces are locally convex topological space that is complete with respect to translation-invariant metric.
>   *It also says that:*
>   They are generalizations of Banach spaces (normed vector spaces that are complete with respect to the metric induced by the norm).
>   *So I am guessing that Frechet spaces are Banach Spaces. But how do we prove it?*

Comment: $X$ is a generalization of $Y$ meaning $Y\subseteq X$... (i.e. every Banach space is a Frechet space)

Comment: Oh, so I got it wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $(B, || \cdot||)$ be a Banach space. Then $d(x,y):=||x-y||$ is a translation-invariant metric on $B$ and $B$ is complete with respect to this metric.

A basis of neighborhoods of $0$ is given by the sets $B_{\epsilon}:=\{x \in B:||x||< \epsilon\}, $  where $ \epsilon >0$.

Each $B_{\epsilon}$ is convex.

Conclusion:  a Banach is a Frechet space.

Answer (score 3):

Fréchet spaces are more general than Banach spaces; every Banach space is a Fréchet space but not vice-versa. If I recall correctly, the difference is that where Banach spaces have a norm inducing the metric in which they are complete, a Fréchet space need not have a norm, just a metric. Although your quote says about the same.

Comment: A Fréchet space may be defined as a complete, locally convex, metrizable topological vector space. Metrizable implies that it admits a metric. Note that Fréchet spaces can have (continuous) norms and still not be Banach e.g. $C^{\infty}(K)$ when $K\subset \mathbb{R}$ is compact, has the property that all its seminorms are norms but none of those yields a complete space (i.e. a Banach space).